# ESP32 panic'ed with string to int

Tags: string, integer, esp32, arduino-esp32, panic

I'm not a specialist in coding, I try to put toghether some code to control over bluetooth a signal generator with ESP32. I managed to make it functional with a number and now I try to conect some variables from BTLE.

Here is my code:

```c
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>

String valor;
long previousMillis_BLE1 = 0;
int interval_BLE1 = 1000;

BLEServer* pServer = NULL;
BLECharacteristic* pCharacteristic = NULL;

#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();



      if (value.length() > 0) {
        valor = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++){
          //Serial.print(value[i]); // Presenta value.
          valor = valor + value[i];
        }

        
       // Serial.print("valor = ");
        Serial.println(valor); // Presenta valor.
      }
    }
};



const byte CPS1 = 3;
const byte CPS2 = 4;

unsigned long TotalTeeth = 10;
unsigned long MissingTeeth = 2;
unsigned long TeethBetweenMissingTeeth = 0;

unsigned long RPM = 800;

//long RPM = valor.toInt();
//unsigned long RPM = valor.toInt();
//int RPM = valor.toInt();
//long int RPM = valor.toInt();


const unsigned long MicrosecondsPerMinute = 1000000ul * 60;


void setup() {

Serial.begin(115200);

  // Create the BLE1 Device
  BLEDevice::init("MyESP32_BLE1");

  // Create the BLE Server
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();

  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                      CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ   |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE
                    );

  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());
  pService->start();

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->start();


  pinMode(CPS1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CPS2, OUTPUT);

}


void loop() {

  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if(currentMillis - previousMillis_BLE1 > interval_BLE1) {
  float TemperatureBLE1 = random(10,60000)/1000.0; // 3 decimals
  float HumidityBLE1 = random(5,99000)/1000.0;  // 3 decimals

  String temperatureBLE1 = String(TemperatureBLE1,3);
  String humidityBLE1 = String(HumidityBLE1,3);
  String tem_hum_BLE1 = temperatureBLE1 + "," + humidityBLE1;

      std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();
      pCharacteristic->setValue(tem_hum_BLE1.c_str()); // Notify.
      pCharacteristic->notify();
      
  previousMillis_BLE1 = currentMillis;     
  interval_BLE1 = random(500,1000);
  }

  unsigned long pulsesPerMinute = RPM * TotalTeeth;
  unsigned long microsecondsPerPulse = MicrosecondsPerMinute / pulsesPerMinute;
  unsigned long microsecondsPerHalfPulse = microsecondsPerPulse / 2;

  for (int i = 0; i < TotalTeeth - MissingTeeth - (TeethBetweenMissingTeeth * (MissingTeeth - 1)); i++)
  {
    Tooth(microsecondsPerHalfPulse);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < MissingTeeth; i++)
  {
    ToothMissing(microsecondsPerHalfPulse);

    // Between pairs of missing teeth, insert this many teeth
    if (i < MissingTeeth - 1)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < TeethBetweenMissingTeeth; j++)
      {
        Tooth(microsecondsPerHalfPulse);
      }
    }
  }


}

void Tooth(int duration)
{
  digitalWrite(CPS1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CPS2, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(duration);
  digitalWrite(CPS1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(CPS2, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(duration);
}

void ToothMissing(int duration)
{
  // two delays for both halves of a missing pulse
  delayMicroseconds(duration);
  delayMicroseconds(duration);

}
```

This part of code is what I try and don't work. I uncoment it one by one to test and every line reboot forever the ESP32.

```c
//long RPM = valor.toInt();
//unsigned long RPM = valor.toInt();
//int RPM = valor.toInt();
//long int RPM = valor.toInt();
```

Do you know any other method to convert the variable "valor" to a number? I think that is a string...

Thank you in advance, Dan

```c
//long RPM = valor.toInt();
//unsigned long RPM = valor.toInt();
//int RPM = valor.toInt();
//long int RPM = valor.toInt();
```

Any of them meet teh ESP32 to panic and reboot forever.

Comment: Those code snippets need to be executed within a function, not as global variable declaration.

Comment: Give me please an example or modify the code thank you.

Comment: Can you give the error message the ESP32 prints?

Comment: Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IntegerDivideByZero). Exception was unhandled. and reboot forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `valor.toInt()` returns 0. This results in `pulsesPerMinute` in `unsigned long pulsesPerMinute = RPM * TotalTeeth;` being equal to zero as well. Then, in the following line `unsigned long microsecondsPerPulse = MicrosecondsPerMinute / pulsesPerMinute;`, there is a division by zero because `pulsesPerMinute` is zero. To solve this, you should place the line `long RPM = valor.toInt();` in the `onWrite` method, because right now, RPM is once calculated, at the start of the program and at that moment valor isn't initialized yet, resulting in `valor.toInt()` returning 0. Besides that, it is advisable to check the value of RPM before calculating the `pulsesPerMinute`.

Example code in which those issues are fixed (I haven't tested this code):

```c
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>

String valor;
long previousMillis_BLE1 = 0;
int interval_BLE1 = 1000;

BLEServer* pServer = NULL;
BLECharacteristic* pCharacteristic = NULL;

const byte CPS1 = 3;
const byte CPS2 = 4;

unsigned long TotalTeeth = 10;
unsigned long MissingTeeth = 2;
unsigned long TeethBetweenMissingTeeth = 0;

long RPM = 800;

const unsigned long MicrosecondsPerMinute = 1000000ul * 60;

#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();

      if (value.length() > 0) {
        valor = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++){
          //Serial.print(value[i]); // Presenta value.
          valor = valor + value[i];
        }

        
       // Serial.print("valor = ");
        Serial.println(valor); // Presenta valor.
      }
      RPM = valor.toInt();
    }
};

void setup() {

Serial.begin(115200);

  // Create the BLE1 Device
  BLEDevice::init("MyESP32_BLE1");

  // Create the BLE Server
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();

  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                      CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ   |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE
                    );

  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());
  pService->start();

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->start();


  pinMode(CPS1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CPS2, OUTPUT);

}


void loop() {

  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if(currentMillis - previousMillis_BLE1 > interval_BLE1) {
  float TemperatureBLE1 = random(10,60000)/1000.0; // 3 decimals
  float HumidityBLE1 = random(5,99000)/1000.0;  // 3 decimals

  String temperatureBLE1 = String(TemperatureBLE1,3);
  String humidityBLE1 = String(HumidityBLE1,3);
  String tem_hum_BLE1 = temperatureBLE1 + "," + humidityBLE1;

      std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();
      pCharacteristic->setValue(tem_hum_BLE1.c_str()); // Notify.
      pCharacteristic->notify();
      
  previousMillis_BLE1 = currentMillis;     
  interval_BLE1 = random(500,1000);
  }

  if (RPM == 0) {
    // handle error, for example:
    Serial.println("RPM is 0, returning from loop...");
    return;

  }
  unsigned long pulsesPerMinute = RPM * TotalTeeth;
  unsigned long microsecondsPerPulse = MicrosecondsPerMinute / pulsesPerMinute;
  unsigned long microsecondsPerHalfPulse = microsecondsPerPulse / 2;

  for (int i = 0; i < TotalTeeth - MissingTeeth - (TeethBetweenMissingTeeth * (MissingTeeth - 1)); i++)
  {
    Tooth(microsecondsPerHalfPulse);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < MissingTeeth; i++)
  {
    ToothMissing(microsecondsPerHalfPulse);

    // Between pairs of missing teeth, insert this many teeth
    if (i < MissingTeeth - 1)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < TeethBetweenMissingTeeth; j++)
      {
        Tooth(microsecondsPerHalfPulse);
      }
    }
  }


}

void Tooth(int duration)
{
  digitalWrite(CPS1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CPS2, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(duration);
  digitalWrite(CPS1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(CPS2, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(duration);
}

void ToothMissing(int duration)
{
  // two delays for both halves of a missing pulse
  delayMicroseconds(duration);
  delayMicroseconds(duration);

}
```

**EDIT:** Removed double declaration and changed type of RPM to right type.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, - Compilation error: 'RPM' was not declared in this scope - is the error that give when I insert when you say. If I insert it in another place, it compiles but reboots forever the esp32. Unfortunately, I don't see how I can put one time more the entire code in my comments, it is my first ask for help. Unfortunately, I use a slider in MIT App Inventor as "acceleration", so I need that anytime can change the RPM.

Comment: I've fixed some mistakes in the code in my answer. Can you try it again?

Comment: Sir... sir... sir... you're a genius!!! It works!!! I need your phone number :) I'm serious, in the future I will need more help, sure. Now I must be a genius and see where I was wrong. An afternoon and a night test all that I find on the internet... Huh... you are a genius!!! Now to find where can I mark that your answer solves my problem, thank you very, very much.

Comment: You can accept my answer as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow). Besides that, if you want to continue programming, I highly recommend to learn somewhat more about variables, scope functions et cetera. There are plenty of good tutorials and resources about Arduino available online.